# "Warning: Task "babel" not found. Use --force to continue."

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webstorm, babeljs

I have this simple code on my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
 require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

  grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          "dist/app.js": ["src/app.js"]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ["babel"]);

};
```

But show me this error when run:

```
Warning: Task "babel" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Any help? Never convert from ecmascript 6  to 5 :(

Here My files:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/nabq78bs323u47b/DemoBable.zip

Comment: also try to explain what you're trying to do

Comment: I want traslate javascript ecma 6 (game.jsx)  to ecma 5 using babel

Comment: can you share all files in your project?

Comment: Yes here : http://www.mediafire.com/download/nabq78bs323u47b/DemoBable.zip

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about a *Python library* with the same name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I downloaded your code to try to help you. I did it. Please see my steps belows:

Step 1: Go to the root project directotry

```
cd DemoBable
```

Step 2: Install `grunt`

```
npm install --save-dev grunt
```

Step 3: Install `load-grunt-tasks`

```
npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks
```

Step 4: Install `grunt-babel`

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-babel
```

Step 5: Finaly, run it

```
grunt
```

The output should be:

```
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task

Done, without errors.
```

**EDITED**

To convert to code to ecma 5. Your `gruntfile.js` should be:

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
    require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

    grunt.initConfig({
        "babel": {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                presets: ['es2015']
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    "dist/app.js": "src/app.js"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["babel"]);
};
```

And you have to install `babel-preset-es2015`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: Hi , works thanks !!! only a question .... the ouput result is the same code on dist folder, dont convert from ecma 6 to 5, you know the why? :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the `load-grunt-tasks` part!